# Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<> to System.Collections.Generic.List<>

Tags: c#, wcf

I've got WCF service which contains List with data from LibW.dll(my dll). In main program I also have got list from LibW.dll.

I return list from WCF service

```
[OperationContract]
public List<IWeather> Final()
{
    return returner;
}
```

and then try to set the result of method to value

```
cont = e.Result;
```

where

```
List<LibW.IWeather> cont=new List<LibW.IWeather>();
```

But I've got such error
Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<object>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<NavigationGadget.IWeather>`

What's wrong?

Comment: See [Do i *have* to use ObservableCollection in Silverlight WCF client?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1911441/119477)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presumably `e.Result` is an `ObservableCollection<T>` then... even if you've declared it as a `List<IWeather>` in your service.

It looks like you *also* need to cast from `object` to `IWeather` - assuming each result really *is* an `IWeather`. You could always *copy* it to a list, like this:

```
cont = e.Result.Cast<IWeather>().ToList();
```

... or change your variable type so it can handle any `IList<IWeather>`.

Comment: Now I've got error = Cannot convert type System.Collections.Generic.List<object> to System.Collections.Generic.List<NavigationGadget.IWeather>

Comment: @Артём Царионов: Okay, with your original formatting (which I've fixed) we couldn't see the type involved. Will edit.

Answer (score 3):

One thing to consider is that in your service reference's configuration (right click on the service reference, then click "Configure Service Reference"), changing the collection type from "Observable Collection" to "System.Collections.Generic.List"